# How to avoid using *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this part of code :

```
<div class="footer" *ngIf="isPartner && canAddNewLang && !deletion"
      fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="row"
      fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlex="100">
      <div class="add-lang"
      *ngFor="let catalog of catalogs"
        routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalog.appId}}/add-new-lang"
        >
        <div class="card__container-header-button" >
          <div class="card__icon-wrapper">
            <svg class="card-button-sml" width="8"
              height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M6.99513 3.1C7.21913 3.1 7.40579 3.17467 7.55513 3.324C7.70446 3.464 7.77913 3.646 7.77913 3.87C7.77913 4.094 7.70446 4.28067 7.55513 4.43C7.40579 4.57 7.21913 4.64 6.99513 4.64H5.03513V6.474C5.03513 6.73533 4.94646 6.95 4.76913 7.118C4.60113 7.286 4.38646 7.37 4.12513 7.37C3.86379 7.37 3.64446 7.286 3.46713 7.118C3.29913 6.95 3.21513 6.73533 3.21513 6.474V4.64H1.29713C1.07313 4.64 0.886458 4.56533 0.737125 4.416C0.587792 4.26667 0.513125 4.08 0.513125 3.856C0.513125 3.632 0.587792 3.45 0.737125 3.31C0.886458 3.17 1.07313 3.1 1.29713 3.1H3.21513V1.014C3.21513 0.752667 3.29913 0.538 3.46713 0.37C3.64446 0.202 3.86846 0.118 4.13913 0.118C4.40046 0.118 4.61513 0.202 4.78313 0.37C4.95113 0.538 5.03513 0.752667 5.03513 1.014V3.1H6.99513Z"
                fill="white" />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <span class="btn__text">
            {{ 'apps.add-new-language' | translate }}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- undo delete -->
     </div>
```

where I show a button and direct user to a path and here is the problem.
I have

```
  *ngFor="let catalog of catalogs"
    routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalog.appId}}/add-new-lang"
```

I am using

```
routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalog.appId}}/add-new-lang"
```

to direct the user in the right path and I need the catalog, for the moment 
I don't know another way except by using for, but in this way, I am showing the button like three times and that is definitely wrong. So the catalog is

```
 @Input() catalogs: IAppInfoModel[];
```

and IAppInfoModel

```
export interface IAppInfoModel {
  appIdToSearch: number;
  appId: number;
  ..............
}
```

By `console.log (this.catalogs);`  I have :
catalogs

```
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (2) [{…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (2) [{…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (2) [{…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (2) [{…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (2) [{…}, {…}]
catalog-group.component.ts:35 (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

this is one of them looks with there propertys :

```
allVersions: [{…}]
appId: 7
appIdToSearch: 40
appMedias: []
bookMarked: false
companiesSize: []
companyId: undefined
companyName: "testCompany 2.0"
deletionRequested: false
easyUseScore: null
enabled: true
featureScore: null
features: []
featuresSummary: []
hasLogo: false
integratedApps: []
languageId: 2
pricing: []
supportedDevices: []
supportedLanguages: []
totalScore: null
typesOfSoftware: [{…}]
valueMoneyScore: null
vendor: "testCompany 2.0"
versionAppDescription: undefined
versionAppName: "sdfsdf"
versionAppWebsite: undefined
versionId: 200
versionLogoExtention: undefined
versionNumber: 1
versionShortAppDescription: null
versionStatusId: 1
versionUpdatedAt: undefined
```

and for 
I don't have much experience in angular so please if you have any idea please help me.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd is different than what you included in largest snippet. Please include correct one that is actually your code.

Comment: If you only want to show the first element of an array, `<div class="add-lang" routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalogs[0].catalog.appId}}/add-new-lang" >`

Comment: @Eliseo I  have tried this , GET Cannot read property 'appId' of undefined

Comment: Can you please show what's in `catalogs`?

Comment: one min I will add it to the question

Comment: use ngif then restrict

Comment: @ORBIT can you show me, cause I don't understand how  can I do this with ngif

Comment: If you always want the first catalog, then use: `routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalogs[0].appId}}/add-new-lang"`

Comment: @llia can you show your array then i will giove solution

Comment: I will now edit the question

Comment: The actual value of `catalogs` as shown by `console.log(catalogs);` would me more helpful than the definition. Also, maybe you get the error "Cannot read property 'appId' of undefined" because on load `catalogs` is not initialized yet, in that case, try with `routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalogs[0] && catalogs[0].appId}}/add-new-lang"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this out**

```
<div *ngFor="let catalog of catalogs; let i = iindex as i; first as isFirst">
    <div *ngIf="isFirst" class="row" routerLink="/partner/my-apps/{{catalog.appId}}/add-new-lang">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
*ngFor="let catalog of catalogs"
```

To this:

```
*ngIf="catalogs[0] as catalog"
```